# How do I make Kingfisher KFImage "reload" or "refresh" a view when the locally cached image has been updated?

Tags: swiftui, kingfisher

I have a KFImage in my view that downloads from a URL, caches and displays an image.

```
                       KFImage(source: kfSource)
                            .onAppear {
                                if let uarl = URL(string: animal.picFileReference) {
                                    kfSource = Source.network(ImageResource(downloadURL: uarl))
                                }
```

Then my user has the option to pick a new image with a PhotosPicker:

```
             PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem,
                                         matching: .images,
                                         photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                                Text("\(Image(systemName: "camera"))")
                                    .font(.title2)
                            }.onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
                                Task {
                                     if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                                         selectedImageData = data
                                         saveAnimalPic()
                                     }
                                 }
                            }
```

which I store as Data (selectedImageData) and use it to create a new RawImageDataProvider. This allows me to run the new image through Kingfisher filters.

```
        let size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        let processor = DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: size) |> BlackWhiteProcessor()
        let rawDP = RawImageDataProvider(data: selectedImageData!, cacheKey: "tmp-img")
        KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: Source.provider(rawDP), options: [.processor(processor)]) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let cache = ImageCache.default
                    cache.store(value.image, forKey: animal.picFileReference) //store new image in cache so changing source below has new one
                    cache.removeImage(forKey: "tmp-img", processorIdentifier: processor.identifier) //remove temp "new and processed" image
```

Then I update the original KFImage cache with the new image, but I have no idea how to make KFImage "reload" so the new image will show. The HACK I'm using right now is to create new temp source and set the KFImage source to that one then back again:

```
                    let rdp = RawImageDataProvider(data: value.image.pngData()!, cacheKey: "tmp-ani-pic") //create new source for KFImage
                    kfSource = Source.provider(rdp) //update source to force refresh KFImage
                    cache.removeImage(forKey: "tmp-ani-pic") //remove tmp image for updating source
```

....but this seems wrong. I feel like there is a better approach. How can I tell KFImage that the image in the cache is new and needs to be reloaded without toggling the source?